# Business scenarios where we can create provider hosted apps?

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Suppose we have office 365 a/c. we want to create some provider hosted apps for trial purpose. For our knowledge I want to know business scenarios where we can create provider hosted apps?

What are those scenarios?

Comment: How would you define 'business scenario'?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  MSDN has plenty of samples and simply browsing the store can give you more ideas.  Any "Scenerio" could be an acceptable one for provider hosted app.